# Should I refresh access token on API

Tags: rest, api, authentication

There is a case when a specific authorized user changes his password or email. As email or password is part of user authentication, I think that it is necessary to revoke all auth tokens.

What is the best practice to refresh auth token in the case where a user has changed their password or email?

I do not use OAuth but have usual **Bearer token** in a header.
The idea is to store on the client side an additional **refresh token**, every time the mail or password changes, we do revoke his access token. After this user can make a request with refresh token to get new access token

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your backend (Ruby on Rails, NodeJS, etc) there will be different approaches. [This is an excellent blog post](https://hackernoon.com/your-node-js-authentication-tutorial-is-wrong-f1a3bf831a46) (warning: some colourful language used in that post) which goes over some authentication pitfalls, in particular resetting a password.

To be honest, are you sure you need to have a refresh token at all?

Why not simply issuing a new Bearer token using the updated credentials to the currently active session (the one that made the email/password change request)?

**Case 1: authenticated session of user**

User has active session(s) and updates their password or email from one of these sessions

- invalidate the sessions that we're not used to update the password/email
- no reason to assume the account has been hacked (they are already logged in, 
  assuming you also expire your auth tokens in a reasonable time frame)
- issue new Bearer token using updated credentials (password/email)
- best practise: send an email to the account
  confirming the password change

**Case 2: forgotten password**

User is logged out and requests a password change (not that you asked for this specifically, but also why no refresh token is needed even if using a special session):

- send the reset link
- user clicks that link, which creates a special session where they are logged in 
  and can update their password
- user updates their password, invalidate all other sessions (if any), issue a 
  new valid auth token to the current session based on updated credentials
- best practise: force them to update the password before taking any other action

Hope this answers your question!